# How to interpret patterns occuring in convolutional layer after training?

Tags: image-processing, conv-neural-network

I am pretty sure I understood' the principle of cnn and why they are prefered over just fully connected neural networks. What I try to comprehend is how to interpret the occuring patterns after training the model.

So let's assume I want to recognize the number "1" written on an 256x256 big image-plane (only 1 bit image, black/white) that is then forwared to the output that either says "is a one", or "is not a one".
If the model is untrained and the first handwritten "1" is forwared, the result could be "[0.28, 0.72] which is obiously wrong. I then calculate the error between [0.28, 0.72] and [1, 0] (for example based on the mean squared error), derive it and try to find the local minimas of the derivative (backpropagation). Then I calculate the delta values for each weight (by using chainrule and partial derivative) until I finally reach the convolutional layer for which delta values are also calculated.

But my question now is: What exactly do the patterns that will occur by adding up bunch of delta values to the convolutional layer "weights" mean? Why do they find certain features characteristical for the number "1"? Or is it more like, it does not find any specific features per se, but rather it "encodes" the relationship between handwritten "1"s and the desired output [1, 0] into the convolutional layers?

_

Comment: Honestly, this is my goto video that I direct people to for getting a simple understanding of conv nets. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aircAruvnKk. It does a great job of teaching with visuals to make neural networks less of a black box.

Comment: you can sort of think of a conv net layer as the same as an image filtering kernel. It's a kernel that encodes some pattern which, when run over the image, finds edges or corners or other shapes that tend to be found in a certain type of image (finding the straight line or hooked "hat" of a one).